# Classes in custom gradle plugin in buildSrc will not be packaged into the apk

Tags: android, gradle

I built a custom gradle plugin in buildSrc. 
My problem is that the classes in buildSrc of this gradle plugin will not be packaged into the apk. 
It seems that only build-related things can be done in buildSrc.

This is different from building a custom gradle plugin in a separate project and publishing it， which allows the modules that depend on this plugin to be able to package and use the code of this plugin.

Comment: Could you use an example to illustrate what you are attempting? Things declared in `buildSrc` are available to the _build_ of your project, not to the runtime, Android or other. And that remains true whether the plugin is published in binary form or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the question is solved by upload the plugin to both jcenter repo and gradle plugins repo.@LouisJacomet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload the custom plugin lib to Jcenter and now I can depend on this plugin.

So it is concluded that if your code does not need to depend on the code in the gradle custom plugin, then you do not need to upload the plugin to the maven library.
You only need to rely on the plugin at compile time. 
Otherwise, you need to upload to the maven library and depend on it.